# WPF Listview modification

Tags: wpf, listview, wpf-controls, mouseevent, listviewitem

For a very specific reason I want to select `ListViewItem`s on mouse button up, not actually on mouse button down. I want this behaviour to be embedded in the control. Is it possible to achieve this? can anyone give hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aviad P.'s answer is a good one and a clever use of attached properties, but I tend to use a different technique most of the time:

1. Subclass ListViewItem.
2. Override OnMouseLeftButtonDown and OnMouseRightButton to do nothing.
3. Override OnMouseLeftButtonUp / OnMouseRightButtonUp to call base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown / base.OnMouseRightButtonDown.
4. Subclass ListView.
5. Override GetContainerForItemOverride() to return your ListViewItem override

This seems easier to me than subscribing to ItemContainer events and adding handlers dynamically.

This is what it looks like:

```
public class MouseUpListViewItem : ListViewItem
{
  protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e) {}
  protected override void OnMouseRightButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e) {}

  protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
  }
  protected override void OnMouseRightButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnMouseRightButtonDown(e);
  }
}
public class MouseUpListView : ListView
{
  protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
  {
    return new MouseUpListViewItem();
  }
}
```

I like this technique because there is less code involved.

Comment: Good answer, I managed to implement my attached property solution, but it turned out just a little bit too complicated and tricky than I hoped! :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's definitely possible using attached properties. Define an attached property called `SelectOnMouseUp` and when it's set to true, hook to your `ItemsContainerGenerator` events to discover when a new item container is added. Then when you get an event for a new item container, hook into its `PreviewMouseDown` and ignore it (set `e.Handled` to true), and hook into its `MouseUp` event and perform the selection (set `IsSelected` to `true`).

Comment: Thanks for reply, is it possible to it in XAML anyway?

Comment: You can't 'mask' the normal `MouseDown` behavior in pure XAML.

Comment: +1 for clever use of attached properties and `ItemContainerGenerator`, but see also my answer which solves the problem more simply using `GetContainerForItemOverride`